# REST Service not registering form data

Tags: javascript, web-services, rest

I'm designing a REST service to allow students to log and register to a website that will list the courses that are available to them but I'm stuck at having the student's even log in or register.  Here's the header response when I try and even get the console in firebug to retrieve a student.  When I try to register I don't even get a response header.

```
GET http://localhost:8080/CP/CoursePlanner/Planner_Service/Students/rlstric1
/CP/ (line 16) //line 16 is xmlhttp.send();
HeadersCookies
Request Headers
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Type    applicaion/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie  __iswl_localhost:8080=0
Host    localhost:8080
Referer http://localhost:8080/CP/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
```

Javascript

```
function getStudentByEmail(url) {
        var username = document.getElementById("studform").studentusername.value;
        url = url + username;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true)
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "applicaion/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

HTML

```
<form id="studform" method="GET">
    Enter student username:  <input type="text" id="studentusername" value="rlstric1">
    Enter password:       <input type="password" id="studentpass" value="test">
    <button id="login" onclick=getStudentByEmail("http://localhost:8080/CP/CoursePlanner/Planner_Service/Students/")>Login</button>
    </form>
```

Here's my service for the planner.  The global @Path is Course_Planner.  I hard coded the password in as "test".

```
@Path("/Students/{username}")
    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public static String loginStudentByUsername(@PathParam("{username}") String username)
    {
        PlannerFacade pf = new PlannerFacade();
        Student x = pf.getStudentByUsername(username, "test");
        return x.toString();
    }
```

Here's the Facade method

```
public Student getStudentByUsername(String username, String password)
    {
        Student stud = null;
        try
        {
            String x = password;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT password FROM Students WHERE password=?");
            stmt.setString(1, password);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next())
            {
                password = rs.getString("password");
                if(!x.equalsIgnoreCase(password))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Lastname, Firstname, Email, ID, Major, password FROM Students WHERE username=?");
                    stmt.setString(1,username);
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        String lname = rs.getString("Lastname");
                        String fname = rs.getString("Firstname");
                        String email = rs.getString("Email");
                        int ID = rs.getInt("ID");
                        String major = rs.getString("Major");
                        stud = new Student(lname, fname, email, ID, major, password);
                    }
                    return stud;
                }
            }
        }catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stud;
    }
```

Spent 8 hours just trying to get the Student to show up in an alert();  I can't even get that to pull from the DB let alone getting someone to register..

Comment: Why is your JAX-RS method `static`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I'm deploying my REST Service I cannot just refresh the page. After deployment from Eclipse I have to manually stop and start the deployed package in apache, then it works fine. For some reason refreshing the page after deployment causes the Reference Error even though the new deployed package was active. I'm sure it was the new deployed package because I would change letters in a

tag and they would change upon refreshing.

Oh well, I fixed my problem though.